# How can I merge results using entity framework and bind the results to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hi all I have written the following query to get the information based on technology id, and I am getting results properly but as I don't know how can I merge the results as per my requirement

The loop will processed based on the grid which is loaded with results, when there are 2 rows this loop will run for multiple times then I will get result on each and every loop, that records I would like to bind together for the result grid, like we merge datasets I would like to merge the results

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdForum.Rows)
{
int quesID = Convert.ToInt16(grdForum.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["TechID"].ToString());
var lastpost = db.tblQuestions.Where(u => u.TechID.Equals(quesID)).OrderByDescending(u => u.DatePosted).Take(1).ToList();
grdnewUser.DataSource = lastpost.ToList();
grdnewUser.DataBind();
}

 public class Results
    {
        public DateTime DatePosted;
        public string QuestionTitle;
        public string UserName;
    }

public void bindLastPost()
{
   ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
   foreach (GridViewRow row in grdForum.Rows)
   {
    int quesID = Convert.ToInt16(grdForum.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["TechID"].ToString());
    var lastpost = db.tblQuestions.Where(u => u.TechID.Equals(quesID)).OrderByDescending(u => u.DatePosted).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

    a.Add(new Results { DatePosted = lastpost.DatePosted, QuestionTitle = lastpost.QuestionTitle, UserName = lastpost.UserName });
   }
      grdnewUser.DataSource = a;
      grdnewUser.DataBind();
```

as per `user1974729` answer

```
int[] quesID;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdForum.Rows)
            {
                quesID[i] = Convert.ToInt16(grdForum.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["TechID"].ToString());
                i++;
            }
            //Check this part to find out how u will implement the Contains in Linq
            var lastpost = from e in db.tblQuestions where quesID.Contains(e.TechID) select e;

            }
```

Comment: Not really sure if I understand your question correctly, but can't you just use AddRange method?

Comment: do you want to merge results fetched from database with results already existing in the gridview?

Comment: Hi check my edits daryal and niaher

Answer (score -1):

```
u r doing this inside the foreach loop//
No matter how many times u do this , only the last time u do it will stick..
grdnewUser.DataSource = lastpost.ToList(); //This is done only one time
```

**So i guess what u r looking for is how to implement CONTAINS in Linq ..**

```
int[] quesID;
int i = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdForum.Rows)
{
 quesID[i] = Convert.ToInt16(grdForum.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["TechID"].ToString());
 i++;
}

//Check this part to find out how u will implement the Contains in Linq
var lastpost = db.tblQuestions.Where(u => quesID.Contains(quesID)).OrderByDescending(u => u.DatePosted).Take(1).ToList();
grdnewUser.DataSource = lastpost.ToList();
grdnewUser.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Hi error `'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: that is why i said //Check this part to find out how u will implement the Contains in Linq .. if that is what u r looking 4..

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx .... if u r looking to write an IN(quesid1,quesid2,quesid3,quesid4) , that is the  link 2 refer

Comment: Hi check my edits I am getting an error as `Use of unassigned local variable 'quesID'`

Comment: dunno u will have to put a breakpoint inside the loop to check if quesID is being initialised.

Comment: Getting the error at the time of building my application, so how can I put a breakpoint